# conformally euclidean metric on riemannian surface

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

We know that in euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$ the euclidean metric induces on a 2-dimensional surface a riemannian metric which can be brought into conformal form by means of a local change of coordinates; can you provide a counterexample to this: for any n-dimensional riemannian manifold we can find a change of coordinates to conformal metric ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking if every $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold is conformally flat. As noted in the example section of [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformally_flat), there are well-understood obstructions to this. In particular, any simply-connected closed $n$-manifold not diffeomorphic to $S^n$ will give you a counter-example (see also [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64874/locally-conformally-flat-manifold/64943#64943) by Robert Bryant). Examples of such are [exotic spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere).